# Distinguish between JSON object and JSON array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to validate a JSON payload to contain a JSON object for particular field. As far as I can see, both JSON objects and JSON arrays are converted to PHP arrays in Laravel's `Illuminate\Http\Request`

*See the example below.*

**Controller.php**

```
private static function getType($o) {
    if (is_object($o)) {
        return "Object";
    } else if (is_array($o)) {
        return "Array";
    }
    return "Unknown";
}

public function test(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $response = [];
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $response[$key] = Controller::getType($value);
    }
    return response()->json($response);
}
```

`test` is the function that get hits on an HTTP request.

Here is a sample request and response from **Controller.php**

**Request**

```
{
    "obj1": {},
    "obj2": {
        "hello": "world"
    },
    "arr1": [],
    "arr2": ["hello world"]
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "obj1": "Array",
  "obj2": "Array",
  "arr1": "Array",      
  "arr2": "Array"
}
```

Is there a way I can validate fields `obj1` and `obj2` to only contain **JSON objects** here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's `Illuminate\Http\Request` decodes a JSON request in the `json` function using

`json_decode($this->getContent(), true)`

Using `true` for the second parameter `$assoc` makes `json_decode` convert all objects into associative arrays.

I made the following changes to **Controller.php**

```
$input = $request->all();
```

was changed to

```
 $input = json_decode($request->getContent());
```

Here is a sample request and response from *modified* **Controller.php**

**Request**

```
{
    "obj1": {},
    "obj2": {
        "hello": "world"
    },
    "arr1": [],
    "arr2": ["hello world"]
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "obj1": "Object",
  "obj2": "Object",
  "arr1": "Array",
  "arr2": "Array"
}
```